# How do I debug a Chromium extension?

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to debug a Chromium extension with `console.log()`, but I noticed that nothing is appearing in my JavaScript console. I assume the console object for the extension is not the same `console` that the document has access to, so how do I dumb a variable into JSON so I can see the result. I'm looking to get something like `console.log()` with Firebug.

Comment: Which part are you trying to debug? Content script, background page, popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Javascript console does not work for extensions, in order to see the console for the extension, you have to:

- Right click on the Browser icon
- Click Inspect Popup

That window has the Console for your extension.