# How can I debug Javascript errors while writing Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I see javascript error when loading chrome extensions? I've tried using developer tools but I don't see any errors there. Also if I use `console.log`, I don't see any output in the console.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I debug a Chromium extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782924/how-do-i-debug-a-chromium-extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html

1. Go to the Extensions page (chrome://extensions), and make sure Developer mode is still enabled. The Extensions page doesn't need to be open for the following to work. The browser remembers the setting, even when the page isn't shown.
2. Right-click the extension's icon   and choose the Inspect popup menu item. The popup appears, and a Developer Tools window like the following should display the code for popup.html.

Comment: I clicked Inspect active views background.html and it opened me popup like you said.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above answer doesn't work anymore. Sadly the Inspect Popup menu item has been removed from Chrome.

But this answer works:
[Debug popup.html of a Chrome Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039875/chrome-extension-debug-popup-html)

(More precisely: the second comment of the first answer on the above page helps).